# Google OAuth: How to convert authorization code to access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, google-oauth, django-authentication, google-api-python-client

From my client side, I have taken an authorization code using the `google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient()` with `ux_mode` set to `popup`. I would be passing the code to my server side so it could be the one making calls to the API. I'm trying to follow the following step provided by Google:

> After your backend platform receives an authorization code from Google and verifies the request, use the auth code to obtain access and refresh tokens from Google to make API calls.
>
> **Follow the instructions** starting at [Step 5: Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code) of the *Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications* guide.

But I have no idea how how to configure it.

```
class GoogleAuthorizationView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        authoriztion_code = request.data.get("authorization_code")
        if authoriztion_code is None:
            return Response(
                {"error": "Please provide a valid authorization code"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )

        flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            "path/to/client_secret.json",
            scopes=[
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read",
            ],
            # I only added this because it's giving me error if not present.
            redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/google-authorize/", 
        )

        flow.fetch_token(code=authoriztion_code)
        credential = flow.credentials

        print(credential)
```

This is my attempt to exchange my code to access token, but it's giving me `(invalid_grant) Bad request`. For context, I am using Django on my backend. What did I miss? Am I supposed to use `Flow`? I don't really need to redirect the user.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to mix clients it in serviceite in this manner why not just let the Python server side code handle the authorization